# R: better to overload base functions or give them new names?

Tags: r, overloading

I'm writing a package where I introduce a class which, among other things, contains a data frame. I'd like the user to be able to use some standard functions on this data frame, such as `table()` and probably others, but since they're not defined as methods in `base`, I can see no other way to achieve this than to mask them like so:

```
table <- function(...) UseMethod("table")
table.default <- function(...) base::table(...)
table.myclass <- function(data,...) {
    … some custom code of mine …
}
```

Is this good practice, or should I rather introduce completely new names, like `makeTable()` and so on? On the one hand, I don't want to add to how much users need to learn, but on the other it doesn't seem to me that seeing "The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:" every time you load the library will earn my package much trust.

Comment: I would read up on generics - https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#generics-and-methods is a very good place to start.  You don't need to redefine this functions, you just need to add a method for your class.

Comment: I've always laughed about that specific example of `cbind` versus `cbind.data.frame`, where it is inconsistent with S3 method dispatch (missing `UseMethod` and `cbind.default`, that is). I agree that masking can be annoying, though if you choose to do it, transparency here is "easy enough" to be convincing. Regardless, you are likely to get a few different opinions here, and unfortunately SO specifically aims to avoid questions that are [*primarily opinion-based*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). (BTW: you don't need to mask, just define `cbind.myclass`, doesn't it work by itself?)

Comment: If you want your object to act like a data.frame, then maybe it should just be a data.frame with an additional class. If it inherits from data.frame, then all the usual data.frame stuff would work. What other things are you storing in the object? Maybe those can be kept in attributes?

Comment: @MelissaKey @r2evans Huh, just adding a method for my class, without masking, works for `cbind()` but doesn't for `table()`. What gives?

Comment: @MrFlick I'll think about it. Maybe that is the better way for me. Thank you.

Comment: table is not a generic function.  (compare `methods(table)` and `methods(cbind)`)

Comment: @r2evans It's definitely not my intention to start an opinion war here. I just thought there maybe was an established practice I didn't know about.

Comment: @MelissaKey Thank you. But this means my question stands at least for `table()` and whatever else I bump into.

Comment: @MrFlick, unfortunately, many R functions do not carry-forward attributes. Try: `attr(mtcars,"a")<-1;newcars<-cbind(mtcars,A=1);attributes(newcars);`. It's a good thought that is defeated by many good intentions in R's pass-by-value/always-copy behavior. I like it in one way but it is incredibly fragile to rely on every other frame-modifying function to preserve attributes.

Comment: @r2evans good point. some overloading would still be required to preserve the attributes. but at least it could still be used by functions that just expect data.frames like `lm()` or `ggplot()` without explicit coercion.